# Comparison between current row, previous row and next row in Talend

Tags: comparison, talend

I want to know if my value is included in an interval consisting of the previous row and the next row. How to do it in Talend?

I tried a `tMemorizeRow` function where I save 3 lines each time, but encountered a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception as when I am on the first line it does not know the next row I saved.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : add a column "sequence" with value as `Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1)`to your data : this way you'll know this exact order between rows in your flow (you can do it in a tMap). Redirect the tMap to a tHashOutput component (if you can't find in the palette, add it through Project Parameters>Designer>Palette>Technique , this component is hidden by default).

Then you'll need an other subjob, with 3 tHashInput : one for your main flow, and the two others as lookup : then you'll be able to join rows with previous and following one , thanks to your 'sequence' field.

[image]

[image]

Then in tMap_2 you'll be able to compare values from mainFlow with Previous and Next flows.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking time. I am doing what you told me but i'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException when i am comparing values from mainFlow with Previous and Next flows. Without comparison it's work. What i am missing ?

Comment: Did you check that the "sequence" field is correctly filled? Do you have incremental value for each line ?  Did you set up the schema correctly for all the ThashInput components ?

Comment: Also, if you want to use previous.newColumn in your output for example, you better check if field is null before applying methods on it (using ternary operator , like : Relational.ISNULL(previous.newColumn)?"No Action":"MyAction")  , or filter output data to work only with not null data